# Iphone UISearchBar Cancel Button Malfunction

Tags: iphone, search, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar that searches and displays results successfully.  If I press the cancel button mid-search, the original table is restored and all is well.  If I press the search button that is on the keyboard, the search results are shown, which is great.  But THEN if I press the cancel button that is on the search bar (I am using the 'search bar and display controller'), the screen goes back to normal, leaving behind only the search results and not showing the original table.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it - I did not know where I could interact with the cancel button that was built into the search bar but I put code that cleaned out the search table in the -searchButtonPressed and threw that in under the search did its work!